# Timer.Enabled = False does not stop Timer tick

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have here my code to send SMS:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    count = DataTable1DataGridView.Rows.Count
    For i As Integer = count To 1 Step -1
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                'dataGridView1()
                ' TextBox1.Text = Me.dataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & DataTable1DataGridView.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).Value.ToString & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(ES_MSG.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & Chr(26))
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("Error on the port selected")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        If (i = count) Then
            Exit For
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
        MsgBox("Message Sent!")
    Next
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

I have enabled timer through a button_click. My problem is timer doesn't seem to stop no matter where I put the Timer.Stop() and Timer.Enabled = False. The worse is when there are errors or when the message is sent, the pop-up seems to appear infinitely even if the count from my datagrid is just small. Can anyone share ideas? I really need it. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590141/timer-cannot-be-stopped-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: I'd start by disabling the timer at the start of the Timer1_Tick otherwise it could refire before it gets to Timer1.Enabled = false.

Comment: -DermFrench, I am actually new to vb and i'm curious about what you are saying.can you please explain more?

Comment: @Sang, simply put, disable the timer BEFORE you call the messagebox...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code after the 'Exit For' will never be called.

Secondly, if your timer events are reasonably frequent, you may find that you have queue of the events waiting to be processed and you're mistaking this for the event still firing. I'd suggest that you disable the timer as the first action in your tick event and re-enable it as the last thing on exit if appropriate:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Dim enableTimer as Boolean = True

    count = DataTable1DataGridView.Rows.Count
    For i As Integer = count To 1 Step -1
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                'dataGridView1()
                ' TextBox1.Text = Me.dataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & DataTable1DataGridView.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).Value.ToString & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(ES_MSG.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & Chr(26))
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("Error on the port selected")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        If (i = count) Then
            enableTimer = False
            Exit For
            ' This code is never hit
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
        MsgBox("Message Sent!")
    Next

    Timer1.Enabled = enableTimer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Timer before but I never encountered any problem without using Timer.Stop, also, you may want to change your code to this:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    count = DataTable1DataGridView.Rows.Count
    For i As Integer = count To 1 Step -1
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then 'I had doubt with this condition, you are testing the same port over and over again
                'dataGridView1()
                ' TextBox1.Text = Me.dataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & DataTable1DataGridView.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).Value.ToString & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(ES_MSG.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & Chr(26))
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("Error on the port selected")
                'Is this an error? You may want to disable your timer here then call Exit Sub
            End If

        If (i = count) Then Exit For
        MsgBox("Message Sent!")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```